# Javascript: How do I tweak my debounce function to take an IF conditional?

Tags: javascript

I found a bug, and tracked it down.
You can [**see a simplified example of my code here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CTcZ9/).

As it turns out, I need to debounce my `if()` statement rather than debouncing the function itself.
I'd like to keep the debounce as a standalone function, but I'm not sure then how to pass the conditional in.

Any pointers?

Here's the code:

```
var foo = function(xyz) {
    alert(xyz);
};

function setter(func, arg1, arg2) {
    return {
        fn: func,
        arg1: arg1,
        arg2: arg2
    };
}

function debounce(someObject) {
    var duration = someObject.arg2 || 100;
    var timer;
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        someObject.fn(someObject.arg1);
        timer = 0;
    }, duration);
}

var toggle = true;

if (toggle) {
    debounce(setter(foo, 'The best things in life are worth waiting for.', 1250));
} else {
    foo('Instant gratification is sweet!!');
}
```

Comment: So what does this do exactly? I know denouncing in electronics but can't seem to figure out how that applies here.

Comment: You could move the `if (toggle) {` check *inside* the `foo` function... That of course, would violate DRY in case you have multiple functions.

Comment: @arttronics From what I understand, OP wants to debounce (e.g. delay) the if-check. He doesn't want to test `toggle` immediately, but later, at the moment the function actually is invoked.

Comment: @Šime Vidas : Yeah, I'm trying to get my code as DRY (do-not repeat yourself) as possible, which is why I'm hoping to keep the debounce as a standalone of some sort.

Comment: @sachleen the real-life implementation is on an input field on a Settings UI.  The inputs have a top and bottom limit (dynamically generated based on environment). If we need to enforce the limits, that naturally has to wait until the user is (or should be) done entering their value. HTH.

Comment: @mOrloff If that is your use case (and you can't use Underscore) you might want too look at their implementation and then you can generate one debounced version of the function and call it as necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using your example, why not pass toggle in as arg 1... something like:

```
var toggle = true;
var debouncedFunk = function(toggle) {
  if (toggle)
    // the function call
  else
    // something else
};
debounce(debouncedFunk, toggle, 1250);
```

You should also look into using the Function objects `.call` and `.apply` methods. They are for calling the function and passing in arguments. Taking the example function:

```
var example = function(one, two) { 
  // Logic here
};
```

You can call it in three ways:

```
// First
example(1, 2);
// Second
example.call({}, 1, 2);
// Third
example.apply({}, [ 1, 2 ]);
```

The first is the standard way to call a function. The difference between the first and the `.call` is that the first parameter to `.call` is the context object of the function (what `this` will point to inside the function), the other parameters are passed after that (and a known list is required for `.call`. The benefit of `.apply` is that you can pass an array to the function of arguments and they will be assigned to the parameter list appropriately, the first parameter is still the context object.

It would simplify your debounce function, instead of having to deal with a structured object as you currently do.

A suggestion for your debounce:

```
var debounce = function(funk, delay) {
  var args = [];
  if (arguments.length > 2)
    args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);
  setTimeout(function() { funk.apply({}, args); }, delay);
};
```

Changing your current if to:

```
var toggle = true;
var debouncedFunk = function(toggle) {
  if (toggle)
    // Do if true
  else
    // DO if false
};
debounce(debouncedFunk, 1000, toggle);
```

Maybe too much information (sorry)?

As a last note, I'd recommend using a framework (if possible) where these functions have been implemented already (and many other useful functions) such as [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/). Using Underscore your example would look like:

```
// Define debouncedFunk and toggle
debouncedFunk = _.bind(debouncedFunk, {}, toggle);
debouncedFunk = _.debounce(debouncedFunk, 1000);
debouncedFunk();
```

**EDIT**

Fixed the underscore example, `_.debounce` returns a function that will execute only after the delay but it still needs to be called.

Comment: **+1** The only thing you left out was the Table of Contents. Excellent Answer!

Comment: Wow @izuriel , that is a **bunch** of great information.  It'll probably take little digesting before I can really comprehend it all :), but that's fantastic. Thanks.

Comment: @mOrloff No problem, I hope it helps you out! And thanks arttronics!