# Conditional debounce, depending on event.keyCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have a search field that takes user input and makes ajax requests using a debounced event listener.

html:

```
<input id="search" type="text"></input>
```

javascript:

```
function makeRequest() {
  // make ajax request, do things with the information
}

$('#search').on('keypress', _.debounce(makeRequest, 200));
```

I need the event listener to *not* use the debounced ajax function on arrow up and down, that is `event.keyCode === 38` or `event.keyCode === 40`

Is there a way to apply the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270275/javascript-how-do-i-tweak-my-debounce-function-to-take-an-if-conditional) question to my problem?

Comment: PiniH's answer should be marked as correct one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that the callback to the event listener needs to call the function returned from `_.debounce`, not just create the debounced function.

```
$('#search').on('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) {
    // do other things
    return;
  }
  _.debounce(makeRequest, 200)();
});
```

Comment: This question is incorrect actually, it won't create the debounced effect, but only delay it by 200 ms and then call all in a chain (new debounce is created every time)

Comment: @PiniH Your answer is literally the same as mine. The only difference is that you put the return statement on the same line, and created the debounce function outside of the `keypress` callback. If my answer needs editing, please explain, and explain how it's different than yours.

Comment: @PiniH I understand your point about unnecessary overhead, though.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrBgXy

When you call _.debounce(funciton, time) it will return a new instance of a debounced function, which won't know between each other.

See my codepen for an example.

Comment: PiniH provided a correct answer. Your answer is wrong. The original code will fire once when key is released + 200ms. Your code will keep firing with 200ms delay on every keypress event (which keeps coming when you hold the key).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you save the results and only call the function, creating the function on every keypress creates an unnecessary overhead.

```
var debounced = _.debounce(makeRequest, 200);
$('#search').on('keypress', function(event) {
    // just exit if it's an up or down arrow
    if (event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) return;
    debounced();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to handle the keypress event in a different manner, where you can see the event properties.

Try this instead...

```
$('#search').on('keypress', function(event) {

    // just exit if it's an up or down arrow
    if (event.which === 38 || event.which === 40) return;

    // do whatever you want here, knowing that up or down was not pressed.

});
```

Since your question is not about the `debounce` method you are trying to use, I've removed that from my example so you can focus on the specific issue that you are asking about.

Comment: That's almost it - `_.debounce` returns a function, which needs to be called.  This works with the adjustment of `_.debounce(makeRequest, 200)()`

Comment: Ah okay - I'll adjust it to suit (and fix the typo I just spotted!)

Comment: This doesn't work, because a call to debounce will create a new function every time, so they won't share the timer.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis The question is not about the debounce functionality - it's about how to handle `keypress` correctly.  I have literally zero knowledge of lodash but fixed the problem that was presented.

Comment: @Archer just try your code vs original when you press and hold a key. The original code will fire once when key is released + 200ms. Your code will keep firing with 200ms delay on every keypress event (which keeps comming when you hold the key). So you fixed one problem and introduced another.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis No, I did not introduce a problem.  I fixed the problem that the OP asked about, and the rest of the code is exactly as it was originally posted.  That would be a 2nd problem and *nothing to do with the question*.

Comment: @PauliusLiekis To help you understand I have removed all references to debounce from the answer.  It now specifically focuses on the question that was asked.  Do you understand now?

Comment: Just read the question. It's about debounce. Conditional debounce. If you remove everything related to "debounce" from your answer then you're not answering the question.

Comment: Conditional debounce is a bit tricky thing. You have to understand how debounce works. Just read the answer from PiniH in order to understand the right way to do it.